# How to handle onclicks on hyperlinks most gracefully

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-router-redux

What I want is rendered HTML that looks like this `<a href="/page/my-cool-slug">My cool Slug</a>`.

That means that someone can right-click on the link and open in a new tab. That'll bypass the fancy pushState stuff that react-router provides.

However, if someone makes a regular click, I need to update redux to say what the new slug is (or pagination page or whatever) AND call `browserHistory.push(...)`.

There has to be a simpler way that is convenient. Something that does almost all of this without all the mess. Here's what my application looks like:

```
// imports
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import changeSlug from './actions'

// the function
makeURL(thing) {
  return `/page/${thing.slug}`
}

// this click method
handleClick(event, thing) {
  event.preventDefault()
  this.props.dispatch(changeSlug(thing.slug))
  browserHistory.push(`/page/${thing.slug}`)
}

// the JSX
<a href={makeURL(myobject)}
  onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, myobject)}
>Go to {myobject.title}</a>
```

Also, I tried using `event.target` in the event handler to get to the `a.href` attribute but because the `<a>` tag contains `<span>` elements, then `event.target` is the `<span>` tag I clicked inside the `<a>` element.

Comment: I discovered `Link` from react-router but that doesn't handle the dispatch of the new action.

Comment: you should be calling an action from the component. let link handle the routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `<Link />` from react_router and determine onEnter/etc.
   actions in your `<Route />` (in `<Router />`).
2. Also you can wrap
   your `<a>` in `<span>` and add some attributes to it and handle
   click event.
3. Also you can add `display: block` style to `<a>` => it
   shouldn't wraps by `<span>`

Comment: I used to use the component's `componentDidMount` to take route params and update the redux store. Now it works as expected but my root index.js got more complex since it needs to import a particular app's action function.